# React Router Navbar depending on route

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to style a Navbar Link depending on the current path in my React App, if the path is /create or /add it should change it's styling. Here is what I have so far in my header component:

```
          <div
            id="createLink"
            className={this.state.createClassName}
            onClick={() => this.handleModalToggle()}
          >
            CREATE
          </div>
```

```
  handleActiveLink= () => {
    let path = this.props.location.pathname
     if (path === "/add" | path === "/create") {
       this.setState({createClassName: "nav-link-active"})
     } else {
       this.setState({ createClassName: "nav-link" })
     }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleActiveLink()
  }
```

This works but only after I refresh the page which makes sense but it's not what I want. So I am looking for a way to change the className before even rendered and get the path first (I am using withRouter from react-router-dom)

Comment: react-router-dom has built in functionality to set active class to active route. Use `NavLink` instead. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink and add some logic to set the `activeClassName`. Don't reinvent the wheel and add more of them.

Comment: I avoided using NavLink because it requires a path where to redirect. In my case I only want to open a Modal to Choose some options (creating or adding a entry) which then redirects the user to /create or /add

Comment: In this case I recommend ***not*** storing such transient data in state, it can be simply derived from the props and set as a className in the render function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue appears to be you only check the path when the component mounts and not when it updates. You should also check in `componentDidUpdate`

```
handleActiveLink= () => {
  let path = this.props.location.pathname;
  if (path === "/add" || path === "/create") {
    this.setState({createClassName: "nav-link-active"});
  } else {
    this.setState({ createClassName: "nav-link" });
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.handleActiveLink();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.handleActiveLink();
}
```

In this case I instead recommend ***not*** storing such transient data in state, and simply derive it from the props and set as a className in the render function (or wherever you render it). This way it's computed each render ***when*** the UI is going to be updated by something and will always be up-to-date (i.e. you won't need to worry about lifecycle functions).

```
render() {
  const { location: { pathname } } = this.props;
  const linkClass = ["/add", "/create"].includes(pathname)
    ? "nav-link-active"
    : "nav-link";

  ...

  <div
    id="createLink"
    className={linkClass}
    onClick={() => this.handleModalToggle()}
  >
    CREATE
  </div>
  ...
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And very elegant code as well thank you a lot !